# Evaluating independent expression in angular

Tags: angularjs

In my angular `controller there is an object

```
var button1 = {
                onClick : resetFn,
                elementText : "Reset",
                extradata : "name = \"hello\""
            };
```

In my html i have something like

```
<button  {{button1.extradata}} type="button" ng-click="footer.onClick()">{{button1.elementText}}</button>
```

`button1.elementText` is getting evaluated correctly but `button1.extradata` is not getting evaluated at all. Why is it ??

**Edit** 
I want this `extradata` to make my element flexible. It can contain any string.

Answer (score 1):

Does the button1.extradata always represent the value of name attribute in button tag..?

IF yes than you should do something like this

```
$scope.button1 = {
                    onClick : resetFn,
                    elementText : "Reset",
                    extradata : "hello"
};

<button  name="{{button1.extradata}}" type="button" ng-click="footer.onClick()">{{button1.elementText}}</button>
```

Comment: I want this extradata to make my element flexible. It can contain any string.sorry i missed that info before

Answer (score 1):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sPrFAge1SW2EKbS7pPK4?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<button  name="{{button1.extradata}}" type="button" ng-click="footer.onClick()">{{button1.elementText}}</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.button1 = {
                onClick : "resetFn",
                elementText : "Reset",
                extradata : "hello" 
            };
```

Your code has several syntax error:

1. `var button1` should be replaced with `$scope.button1`.
2. `nClick : resetFn` should be replaced with `nClick : "resetFn"`.
3. `{{button1.extradata}}` attribute inside `button` element should be replaced with `name="{{button1.extradata}}"`.

Comment: I want this extradata to make my element flexible. It can contain any string.sorry i missed that info before

Comment: That is not how angular expression work. You can have a look at [AngularJS expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $scope.button1 = {
                    onClick : resetFn,
                    elementText : "Reset",
                    extradata : "hello"
                };

<button  name="{{button1.extradata}}" type="button" ng-click="footer.onClick()">{{button1.elementText}}</button>
```

Comment: I want this extradata to make my element flexible. It can contain any string. sorry i missed that info before

Comment: then u can try the $sce.trustAsHtml(button1). this will render extradata in to html tag.

in the html inside button tag use  ng-bind-html="button1.extradata". please inject the $sce

Comment: actually u cant put one element like that. if u want to write all the button tags and properties inside controller and render it in html page then the ng-bind-html is the solution. i created a plunker but i don't know this is the answer u r looking for  https://plnkr.co/edit/LDrS6EGL4eMnm1JgWnbi?p=preview